# Unable to get Outside Touch Event of Popupwindow

Tags: android, popupwindow

I am unable to get Outside touch of my Custom Popup Window and my popup should be focusable true because it have some EditText which required soft keyboard .

Here is my code :

```
        mPopupWindowAddnewItem= new PopupWindow(mPopupView,
                mView_add_Popup.getWidth(), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
        mPopupWindowAddnewItem.setContentView(mPopupView);
        mPopupWindowAddnewItem.setFocusable(true);
        mPopupWindowAddnewItem.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        mPopupWindowAddnewItem.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        mPopupWindowAddnewItem.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motion) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(motion.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){
                    showExistDialog();

                    return true;
                }
                else
                if(motion.getAction() ==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    Rect mPopupRect=new Rect();
                    mPopupWindowAddnewItem.getContentView().getDrawingRect(mPopupRect);

                    if(mPopupRect.contains((int) motion.getRawX(),
                                    (int) motion.getRawY())){

                        return false;

                    }else{

                        showExistDialog();

                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        });


        mPopupWindowAddnewItem.showAsDropDown(mView_add_Popup);
```

In my code it always go to inside else if condition and also that rect check of Popup view always return false even i am touching inside PopWindow.
Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my issue by this code :

```
else if(motion.getAction() ==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    Rect mPopupRect=new Rect();
                    mPopupWindowAddnewItem.getContentView().getDrawingRect(mPopupRect);

                    if(mPopupRect.contains((int)motion.getX(),
                                    (int) motion.getY())){

                        return false;

                    }else{

                        showExistDialog();

                        return true;
                    }
                }
```